# Image Rotates and zooms while editing

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a library called [SnapSliderFilters](https://github.com/pauljeannot/SnapSliderFilters) to apply filters to an image. I need the filters to be applied exactly the way it is presented in the library's example.

When I implemented the code exactly as directed on an image captured with a custom camera, sliding sideways, while applying the image filter, it also causes the image to rotate by 90 degrees and the image to zoom.

In other case, when I select an image from gallery, that is of exact dimension as the screen, it works perfectly fine.

So, I think I have found the cause to be image size but I don't know where to begin.

Here is how it displays:

[image: captured image]

[image: image with filter applied]

Comment: How do you export the image?

Comment: never mind i figured out the problem. Turns out the captured image's size was greater than the view's size which caused the image to rotate sideways.